# MySQL select statements across different dates

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I have a table which looks something like this:

```
Month/Year id url     kw_count IMP CLK POS CTR 
Aug-2018    1 /url-1       222 444 122   4 1.2 
Sept-2018   2 /url-1       232 534 123   4 1.2 
Oct-2018    3 /url-1       224 445 124   4 1.2 
Nov-2018    4 /url-1       212 478 125   4 1.2 
Aug-2018    5 /url-2       233 434 126   4 1.2 
Sept-2018   6 /url-2       311 433 128   4 1.2 
Oct-2018    7 /url-2       299 423 123   4 1.2 
Nov-2018    8 /url-2       232 411 122   4 1.2 
Dec-2018    9 /url-2       231 465 156   5 1.1
```

I want to select all unique urls along with their metrics for two separate months. Something like this…
August and September 2018…

`/url-1, kw_count (aug), kw_count (sept), imp (aug), img (sept)...` etc and then the same for url-2

I won't know the URLs before-hand it's simply select based on the dates selected.

I can't for the life of me figures out how I might do this. I've played with `group by` and others but I'm struggling.

How can I do this?

Comment: You mention python. Seriously consider handling display issues in application code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
SELECT url, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Month\Year` = 'Aug-2018' THEN kw_count END) AS `kw_count (Aug)`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Month\Year` = 'Sep-2018' THEN kw_count END) AS `kw_count (Sep)`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Month\Year` = 'Aug-2018' THEN IMP END) AS `IMP (Aug)`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Month\Year` = 'Sep-2018' THEN IMP END) AS `IMP (Sep)`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Month\Year` = 'Aug-2018' THEN CLK END) AS `CLK (Aug)`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Month\Year` = 'Sep-2018' THEN CLK END) AS `CLK (Sep)`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Month\Year` = 'Aug-2018' THEN POS END) AS `POS (Aug)`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Month\Year` = 'Sep-2018' THEN POS END) AS `POS (Sep)`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Month\Year` = 'Aug-2018' THEN CTR END) AS `CTR (Aug)`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Month\Year` = 'Sep-2018' THEN CTR END) AS `CTR (Sep)`
FROM metrics
GROUP BY url
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
url     kw_count (Aug)  kw_count (Sep)  IMP (Aug)   IMP (Sep)   CLK (Aug)   CLK (Sep)   POS (Aug)   POS (Sep)   CTR (Aug)   CTR (Sep)
/url-1  222             232             444         534         122         123         4           4           1           1
/url-2  233             311             434         433         126         128         4           4           1           1
```

When you build the query, you will need to adjust the dates and column names appropriately. I've created a demo [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb6b3c/4) to play with (it would have been much easier if you'd posted text rather than an image of your data!).

Comment: Sorry, I'll make sure I add proper data next time. I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: I can understand what's happening with this but I don't know some of these formats so I'll have to do some research but it's coming out how I need it - so basically, I'd just swap out the dates assuming the column names and table names are aligned?

Comment: Because I'm using a `GROUP BY` clause, I need to have aggregate functions on each variable (`SUM`). The `CASE` expression inside the `SUM` makes sure that the only value I add is the one for that month (so in effect, only one value is ever being added).

Comment: So CASE is a bit like an if statement?

Comment: Ah, man, reading through your code... it's really clever. Thanks so much

Comment: Yes, `CASE` - especially the way I've used it - is just like an `IF`. People tend to prefer to use `CASE` as it is more transportable across different SQL varieties.

Comment: A other tip to @Adders `SUM` only works correctly when pivoting numbers. If you want to pivot other data like strings (VARCHAR, CHAR or TEXT datatypes) or dates in the future you need to use `MAX` function instead of `SUM`.. Offcource `MAX` also works for numbers. When i need pivot in MySQL i always use `MAX` because it works on anny MySQL datatype

Answer (score 1):

Your table contains records per month and url. Now select one month, select another month, join the two data sets and you are done. That would be:

```
select *
from (select * from mytable where month_year = 'Aug-2018') m201808
full outer join (select * from mytable where month_year = 'Sept-2018') m201809 using (url);
```

As MySQL doesn't support full outer joins, we'll have to get the urls first and then outer join both months:

```
select *
from (select distinct url from mytable where month_year in ('Aug-2018', 'Sept-2018')) urls
left join (select * from mytable where month_year = 'Aug-2018') m201808 using (url)
left join (select * from mytable where month_year = 'Sept-2018') m201809 using (url);
```

Of course you should replace `select *` with the column names:

```
select
  url,
  m201808.kw_count as kw_count_201808,
  m201809.kw_count as kw_count_201809,
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I appreciate your feedback